# Chromedriver failing to send input keys

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue with Chromedriver failing to send simulated inputs (Control + P ) on a server. The inputs that I am sending with InputSimulator (http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/). Using Selenium and Firefox, the tests execute perfectly; however when I change over to use Chromedriver, I am encountering failures from my input simulator not properly firing on the page. That is the only difference taking place.

If I perform the test on my local machine instead of on the server, it executes flawlessly. Since InputSimulator just simulates they keys being pressed, it never reports a failure.

The servers that I am running on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 Bit.

Why would Selenium(Firefox) not have any issue and changing to Chromedriver now causes them to never send only one the servers? The only section of code changing is the driver settings.

Selenium (firefox)

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"path/to/profile");
using (IWebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(profile))
{
    //Navigate to URL
    driver.Navigate().GoToURL(@"http://google.com"); 
    //Wait for the page to load 
    Thread.Sleep(2000); 
    InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_P);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
    //Now I have the dialog to send my save path. 
}
```

Chromedriver

```
var options = new ChromeOptionsWithPrefs();
options.prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState","{\"version\":2,\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false,\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\",\"selectedDestinationOrigin\":\"local\",\"customMargins\":null}" }};
     options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
     options.AddArgument("-incognito");
     options.AddArgument("-start-maximized");
     options.AddArgument("--renderer-print-preview");

 using (IWebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(@"C:/Chromedriver/path", options))
 {
    //Navigate to URL
    driver.Navigate().GoToURL(@"http://google.com"); 
    //Wait for the page to load 
    Thread.Sleep(2000); 
    InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_P);
    //Code never fires on the servers; does fire on my local machine.
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you need this library at all?

Comment: I'm simulating a manual print and then using the windows form, I am sending the file path to where I want it to be saved. I save them as PDFs and then convert them to text to find some values. In Firefox, some PDF's do not give select-able text, but Chrome has a "Save as PDF" option that provides readable PDFs when Firefox wouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

InputSimulator does not work in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 if Aero is off (I have not tested with other versions, yet).

For Windows 7, switch to an Aero theme and it will start working again.

For Windows Server 2008 R2, you will need to install Workstation Theme for Aero:

1. Run this command in command prompt:

   > ServerManagerCmd -i Desktop-Experience
2. Restart the server.
3. Go to services.msc and start the Themes service.
4. Go to Windows Display settings, select Personalize, Pick an Aero Theme.